# Navigation in php,trouble in focus

Tags: javascript, php, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a CSS menu in html site:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
      <li class='active'><a href='index.php'><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href='about.php'>About</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Me</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Compeny</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now I converted that html file to php and named "NAVEGATION.PHP" and then I included this file to all over files.
The problem is that the focus (class:active) is stuck on "Home" button.
I would like to that when I change the page the focus of menu is according to page.
I also try a JavaScript, but it's not working for me :

```
$(function () {
var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
$(".cssmenu ul li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
    if ((($(this).attr("href") == 'index.php')||($(this).attr("href") == '')) && (pgurl == '')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
})});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` which will get you current path, and [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php), will extract the filename from path, and thereafter you can simply compare with link on menus

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
     <ul>
            <li <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href='index.php'><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
            <li <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'about.php') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href='about.php'>About</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href='#'>Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'>Compeny</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: assuming code is in php file, also try `echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` - try echoing above, and check what it outputs

Comment: you are not getting me correctly, try echoing `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` in about.php .. it should output `about.php`, let me know.. what output comes

Comment: I put the code <?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?> in about.php. It echos "about.php".

Comment: Okay, it's correct .. actually I've class missing in my code, I've updated my answer. please try again with updated answer

Also make sure you have, style defined for active class

Comment: Yeah it's working but its not for dropdown menu. Its not working when I click on About>Company. Now what should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82779/discussion-between-kamal-pal-and-muhammad-hamza-khan).